# Some Wave Equation Algebra

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, constants

I am trying to solve $u_{tt} = u_{xx}, u(0,\ t) = 0, u(1,\ t) = 0, u(x,\ 0) = \frac{x - x^2}{4}, u_t(x,\ 0) = 0$.  Using separation of variables leads to $\frac{\ddot T}{T}$ = $\frac{X''}{X}$ = $\lambda$.  My solution to the Sturm-Louiville problems is $(X = Ae^{-\sqrt\lambda x} + Be^{\sqrt\lambda x}, T = Ce^{-\sqrt\lambda t} + De^{\sqrt\lambda t})$ if $\lambda \neq 0$ (I think I've ruled out the $\lambda = 0$ case).  Thus I have $u = ACe^{-\sqrt\lambda x - \sqrt\lambda t} + ADe^{\sqrt\lambda t - \sqrt\lambda x} + BCe^{\sqrt\lambda x - \sqrt\lambda t} + BDe^{\sqrt\lambda x + \sqrt\lambda t}$.

It feels like I should be able to somehow lump constants to simplify the problem, but it is also more difficult than in the $1$D Heat Equation, where $T$ had only a single arbitrary constant.  Here, due to the FOILing, there is a situation where if, i.e., $AC$, $AD$, and $BC$ are all positive, then $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ must all have the same sign, so that $BD$ cannot be negative, thus the exponential coefficients are not fully arbitrary.  Can I simplify the constants at all here without modifying the constraints the coefficients impose on each other, as there seem to be too many constants left when I plug in the boundary conditions?  My workflow when solving the Heat Equation was to switch from exponentials to trig via Euler's formula after plugging in the boundary conditions but before plugging in the initial conditions, after it was clear that $\lambda$ came out negative (it always did for the $1$D Heat Equation).  I tried doing the conversion early here to see if constants would go away, by multiplying the exponents by $-i^2$ and applying Euler's formula, but the constants were merely scrambed rather than simplified.

Comment: Your $X(x)$ should satisfy the boundary condition at $x=1$, which gives you a link between $A$ and $B$. Are you looking for bounded solutions? Are your eigenvalues positive or negative?

Comment: @GReyes What I did was plug both boundary conditions into my four-constant expression for $u$ to get an algebraic system of two equations.  I think this is the correct approach, because the boundary conditions state what $u$ is at $x = 0$ and at $x = 1$, not what $X$ is, right?  The question is about a string, so I assume I need solutions where $x$ is between $0$ and $1$.  I think the eigenvalues in the Heat Equation were always complex, but I haven't gotten to that point in the computation in the Wave Equation?  I'm not really sure because different presentations of separation of variables...

Comment: seem to incorporate information from the physics problem or the professor's insight into what will make for nice math when they name constants.  I am trying to use simple constant names and let the algebra show me how things need to be.  This makes the process easier to remember, but also means I might be using $\lambda$ to mean what another presentation means by $\sqrt{-\lambda}$ or something, so I'm not precisely sure which part is the eigenvalue in the PDE (unless you mean the eigenvalues from the Strum-Louiville problems).

Comment: Using your notation, that is $X''/X=\lambda$, your $\lambda$ has to be negative so you get sines as your eigenfunctions. When $\lambda>0$ the solutions for $X(x)$ are combinations of exponentials and the boundary conditions cannot be satisfied. You should obtain $\lambda=-(n\pi)^2$ with $n=1,2,3...$ those give you $\sin n\pi x$ as eigenfunctions

Comment: Your $X$ has to satisfy the boundary conditions. Then you adjust the coefficients in the series to meet the initial condition(s).

Comment: @GReyes I don't understand how $X$ has to satisfy the boundary condition, because the boundary condition says something about $u$, not $X$.  A boundary conditions for $X$ would have to be something like $X(5) = 10$, wouldn't it?

Comment: For $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ to satisfy $u(0,t)=0$ for **all** $t$, you need to have $X(0)=0$ (unless $T(t)$ is identically zero, which is an uninteresting case that can be discarded).

Comment: The boundary conditions on $u$ forces $X$ to be zero at both $x=0$ and $x=1$, and the values of $\lambda$ are determined by those. You get a countable set of lambdas in this case.